# Output inserted row from CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a CTE and I need to populate that CTE with the row that has been inserted.

I tried using temp table.

I am not sure how to create temp table within CTE and fill CTE.

This is what I have tried:

```
WITH RESULT AS
(

DECLARE @INSERTOUTPUT1 TABLE
(
  BOOKID INT,
  BOOKTITLE NVARCHAR(50),
  MODIFIEDDATE DATETIME
 );

-- INSERT NEW ROW INTO BOOKS TABLE
INSERT INTO BOOKS
OUTPUT INSERTED.*  INTO @INSERTOUTPUT1
VALUES(101, 'ONE HUNDRED YEARS OF SOLITUDE', GETDATE());
SELECT * FROM @INSERTOUTPUT1
)
SELECT * FROM RESULT
```

Below is the schema for the table:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Books;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Books
(
  BookID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  BookTitle nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  ModifiedDate datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Forget about the temp table for a moment, can you explain what you want to achieve here ?

Comment: Why did you put so many versions of SQL Server? Which specifically are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you can't have the `declare` statement inside the `CTE`. It should be separate statement. Not sure what you wanted the CTE there for ? but there isn't a need for CTE

```
DECLARE @INSERTOUTPUT1 TABLE
(
  BOOKID INT,
  BOOKTITLE NVARCHAR(50),
  MODIFIEDDATE DATETIME
 );

INSERT INTO Books
OUTPUT INSERTED.*  INTO @INSERTOUTPUT1
VALUES(101, 'ONE HUNDRED YEARS OF SOLITUDE', GETDATE());

select  *
from    @INSERTOUTPUT1
```